# What's the recommended practice for initializing UI within a SPA?

Tags: elm

I'm struggling to figure out how to load data onto a view that's dynamically generated.

Hence, how do I trigger the *update* function on my view so that it can get initialized with web requested data.

Here's how the view gets rendered:

```
case portal.requested of
    Domain.ViewSources ->
        div []
            [ Html.map SourcesUpdated <|
                Sources.view
                    { profileId = portal.provider.profile.id
                    , platforms = model.platforms
                    , source = portal.newSource
                    , sources = loggedIn.profile.sources
                    , isInitialized = False
                    }
            ]
```

**Details:**

I attempted to add the following to my page that my main page calls the *view* function on:

```
main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( init, Cmd.none )
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
        }
```

In the past the module's *update* function would get triggered on key entry and button click events. However, now I need to load in the data from past user sessions. Thus, I'm struggling to trigger the *update* function on when the page first gets viewed by the user.

Here's what I would like to do:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    if not model.isInitialized then
        ( model, runtime.sources model.source.profileId SourcesResponse )
    else ...
```

Here's the [code](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Controls/Sources.elm).

Comment: You can either load the data with JS and pass it as app flag or you can have your `init` function execute a command.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of the face that the init function takes a tuple that includes an initial Command, the result of which is passed to the update function

```
main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( init, runtime.sources init.source.profileId SourcesResponse )
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. However, how do I pass an argument to this main function? I get a compile error when I provide an argument. Hence, model is undefined on the main function.

Comment: where does the parameter you want to pass come from? A flag, some state in your url?

Comment: I decided to embed the parameter as a property of the model that the client provides to the module. However, I'm still stuck on how to call init with state passed as an argument.

Comment: I don't think I understand any more - you seem to be describing an impossible world where there are two main functions?

Comment: Well as a beginner, I'm sure that I'm not explaining myself well. I'm essentially trying to initialize some UI with externally provided data. I need to trigger the update function when this UI is displayed without requiring the actual user to spawn an event to trigger the module's update function.

Comment: can you say where does the 'externally provided data' comes from - possible answers include passed as a flag from Javascript, or it is in the url?

Comment: I have a client module (i.e. main) display a UI region within the application's shell. The main module displays this region by calling another module's (i.e. sources) view function and passes in the model that the "sources module" view function requires.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that I can simply pass in the state to my view function.

```
div []
    [ Html.map SourcesUpdated <|
        Sources.view
            { ...
            , sources = loggedIn.profile.sources
            }
    ]
```

Hence, I was stuck in the *PageLoaded* paradigm of performing app UX using OOP.

Thus, in the example above, I made the client module responsible for initializing the data that the other module's view needs to render.